# Website Hosting Management Software

Tags: iis, hosting

I am looking for a web based application that manages IIS and MS SQL servers.

Preferable one that I can define a workflow process for few various steps (such as a new site request), and that workflow (that creates a new iis site, new sql db, etc) will be automatically executed everytime there is a request.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.websitepanel.net/

Open Source. Former commercial product  and not a bad one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rented box that comes with [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/uk/products/plesk/) and to be fair, it's really not bad at all.

Everything is point and click driven and easy to use, yet comprehensive if you need it to be.

I don't think it's the cheapest on the planet, but give it whirl.